# Raspberry Pi as server - stuck with users and groups

Tags: apache-http-server, ftp, php, raspberry-pi, debian-wheezy

I just installed an apache2 server with php5 and mysql on my RPi (Raspbian Wheezy). I followed this tutorial: tutorial link

Everything went well, even the file transfer via FTP (FileZilla).

I immediately had access to the index.html file ("It Works!"), but had no access to the files I transferred with FileZilla. After some research on the net, I changed users and groups again and again, but nothing helped. Now even the FTP-transfer doesn't work anymore...

Could anybody tell me (and explain why) which permissions/users/groups I have to put on the /var/www directory to access the files local on my Pi and via the Pi's IP 192.168.X.XX ?

EDIT:

```
pi@raspberrypi /var/www $ ls -lah
total 16K
drwxr-xr-t  3 root pi   4.0K Mar 25 15:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4.0K Mar 25 15:06 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi    177 Mar 25 15:07 index.html
drwxr-xr-t  9 pi   pi   4.0K Mar 25 15:22 webtrees
```

Comment: Had no access to the files I transfered with filezilla?   What do you mean by this statement?   Are you trying to edit/view the files from within filezilla or are you on the Raspberry Pi in a terminal trying to access the files?   What user are you logged into the raspberry pi as?   If you type 'whoami' (without the quotes) on the command line it should tell you who are you logged in as.

Comment: On a general note, it is always better to understand what you are doing than just following a tutorial. A good way is to find several tutorial, compare them, and dig the common points/difference to learn about concepts.

Comment: Also if you could run the following command and pastebin or somehow post it here (even a picture from a cell phone would work).   First change directory to your www directory (which I will assume is /var/www/html, but I could be wrong) and type 'ls -lah' and post the results.

Comment: No, I transfered a folder with php files to /var/www on my pi and could not access localhost/folder/index.php. I am logged in as pi (standard user)

Comment: I totally agree Kwaio, but sometimes for someone who is very new to Linux it could be difficult to figure out regardless.   I spent so many nights pulling my hair out back in the Red Hat 7.2 days trying to figure these sorts of things out..

Comment: @hitchcock's_birds are you trying to access these files FROM the raspberry pi itself or are you trying to view the files from another machine?

Comment: @hitchcock's_birds so now FTP transfer is not working anymore?  please give some details as to what is not working.   Is it not letting you authenticate at all?  Does it let you authenticate but when you try to upload it says permission denied?

Comment: also, the tutorial you followed is not linked in the post (or at least I cannot click the link, but I am behind a very restrictive firewall but usually it will allow me to click links but then tell me the site is blocked)..

Comment: Well, I tried to access the files from the Pi itself and from my main machine, from the Pi via "localhost" and from my machine via the pi's ip. Filezilla lets me connect to the server, but uploads fail. Sorry the link is: http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Raspberry-Pi-Web-Server

Comment: the ls -lah output follows, can't copy&paste from Putty and may not upload pictures due to low reputation...

Comment: updated ls -lah output

Comment: Ok so uploads fail with permission denied?   What user are you connecting to the FTP as?  root?   pi?   some other account?   Have you been using the same FTP account the whole time?   Can you access http://localhost/index.html (local) or http://ipaddress/index.html (from another computer)?   Are you totally sure apache is actually up and running?   to be sure try running the 'sudo service apache2 restart' command (without quotes).   The tutorial is very simple and I don't see any issues with it..

Comment: on second thought I do see a possible issue with the tutorial, it has you install apache, restart the service, install mysql server and client and PHP, but nowhere do I see another restart of apache now that you have installed PHP and MySQL.    Nor do I see any instructions to take a look at  your apache config files (usually located in /etc/apache2 or /etc/httpd) to  make sure that it is loading the PHP5 and MySQL modules by default.   Do me a favor, install a command called pastebinit (run 'sudo apt-get install pastebinit').   That way you can run commands and have the output go to pastebin.

Comment: ok, after a restart of apache, I reach the index.html from my Pi (local) and from my main machine. When I navigate directly to localhost/folder/setup.php, it shows me nothing - not even an error. I had a look into the apache.config but couldn't find an entry for php... Installed pastebinit now.

Comment: FTP works again, so I uploaded a php test-page (phpinfo) to the root directory (/var/www) but the browser won't display it. Seems like PHP isn't running...